# Проверка python кода от пользователя

Tags: python, django, input, безопасность

делаю сайт с курсами на django и нужно проверять код от пользователей. Должно это выглядеть так:
[image: выполнение кода]

Знаю про eval, но боюсь, что будет дырка в безопасности. Подскажите безопасный способ реализации. В какую сторону капать?

Cейчас думаю над docker, но не совсем понятно, как запускать контейнер из питона и как передавать в него код, с учетом того, что у каждого пользователя должен быть свой контейнер (как я понимаю)

Comment: Контейнер запускается отдельно. В контейнере установлен сервер, который принимает код, принимает его, компилирует, запускает, возвращает результаты. Этот сервер запускает каждый код как отдельный процесс, у которого установлены ограничения на потребление памяти, CPU, доступ у любым ресурсам. https://www.baeldung.com/linux/sandboxing-process